Stack snippets no longer show logs
The stack snippets have lost their logging ability as of very recently.
Demo. And note that the console in the stack snippet is enabled.


console.log("hello");



Happens in both Firefox and Chrome.
The code does run - you can see the log in the browser's console. Moreover, any DOM manipulations still happen:


document.body.textContent = "hello";



Additional information: It seems that when a snippet is executed, there is a 404 error with GET https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1 which is why the console does not show

For me it looks like https://i.sstatic.net/HC4pdcOy.png, so it seems to be working? Firefox on Ubuntu.

@Marijn Now it seems to work. It didn't use to when I posted the question.

Seems to be an intermittent issue, I couldn't reproduce it before but I can reproduce it now and after a refresh it's back to working again.

Started happening again just now. I added more information - the code for the console doesn't load.

The issue was that the URL references /scripts but the actual folder on disk was Scripts. This was fine and dandy when we were running on Windows, but yesterday we switched the StackSnippets service to run on a Linux-based pod in a Kubernetes cluster and path casing became important.
Caching is a thing and we still had some traffic going to the Windows-based servers, so the bug was appearing intermittently for some folks.
With all that said, this is fixed now. Thanks for the report!

"yesterday we switched the StackSnippets service to run on a Linux-based pod in a Kubernetes cluster" Oh, oh no...

Oh no?  Sounds like an "Oh yes!" to me.  Given the Google Cloud Platform (CGP) announcement, I'll bet they have one or more Google Container Engine (GKE) clusters and are starting to migrate to modern cloud hosting infrastructure, hopefully all managed by Terraform or other infrastructure as code (IaC) tools.

@StephenOstermiller Got it in one :)
